# Formula from wikipedia relating Heisenberg with Schrödinger pictures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution, observables

I have a pretty naive question about a formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) relating operator $A_H $ in Heisenberg picture with it's equivalent  $A_S $ in Schroedinger picture:

$$    \frac{d}{dt}A_\text{H}(t)=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_\text{H},A_\text{H}(t)]+\left( \frac{\partial A_\text{S}}{\partial t} \right)_\text{H} . $$

Shouldn't the right term $ \frac{\partial A_\text{S}}{\partial t} $ be always zero? Isn't every operator in Schrödinger picture by definition time independent or do I missing here something?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11264/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which derivative with respect to time is which in the Heisenberg picture of quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11264/)