# Momentum operator in Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I was reading
[this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/time-evolution-in-quantum-mechanics?noredirect=1&lq=1) since I am still a bit rusty on the idea of Heisenberg picture.

I do believe that I follow the math given in the accepted answer, but then I have run into a problem extrapolating the idea to the following problem.

So let's consider a real scalar field theory with Lagrangian density:

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\psi \partial^\mu\psi -\frac{m^2}{2}\psi^2-V(\psi)$

Then most of the online lecture notes on QFT go on to show that the three momentum operator is:

$p^k(t) = \int d^3x T^{0k}(\vec{x},t) $ where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the energy momentum tensor.

Next, they also prove that: $-i\partial^k\psi(x) = [p^k(t),\psi(x)]$, and I have done the work myself and I can understand things up to here.

Now, this equation looks strikingly similar to the time evolution of operator in the Heisenberg picture (assuming the operator does not explicitly depend on time).

i.e. $-i\frac{dA}{dt} = [H,A]$ and for this, the related question shows that we can write:

$A(t) = e^{iHt}A(0)e^{-iHt}$  where $A(t)$ is in Heisenberg picture and $A(0)$ is in Schrodinger picture.

Now, going back to $-i\partial^k\psi(x) = [p^k(t),\psi(x)]$, I naively thought that this would mean:

$\psi(\vec{x},t) = e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} \psi(\vec{0},t)e^{-i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}}$

Turns out I got the exponentials switched. However, I don't know why that is the case. Could someone maybe give me a hint as to why the correct expression would be:

$\psi(\vec{x},t) = e^{-i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} \psi(\vec{0},t)e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}}$

Also, is the way I am drawing this analogy faulty in any way?

Answer (score 1):

One way to see that the exponential must have that sign is that in the end the phase needs to be Lorentz invariant. In other words
$$
\psi(\vec{x},t) = e^{-ip\cdot x + i E t} \,\psi(0,0)\, e^{ip\cdot x - i E t}\,.
$$
If there was a plus then the expression at the exponent would not be invariant under boosts.

Also let me remark that this equation holds only for the free theory ($V(\psi)=0$) or for the in and out-states of the interacting theory.

I'm not sure where exactly you lost that minus sign. Perhaps it has to do with the index up vs index down and the metric convention (mostly plus versus mostly minus) that your lecture notes use.